# Switch user in winSCP

Tags: linux, unix, winscp

I'm using winSCP to access Unix computers.

How can I change user after I have logged into a Unix server using winSCP?

E.g. I have personal account in unix computer A. I can log into this comp using Putty and then change user to root user `$sudo /usr/bin/su - rootuser`.

How can I do the same thing using winSCP? I don't know the password for rootuser

Comment: Consider adding an OS tag for libraries / utilities specific to an OS.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You can only login with a username/password credintials or a ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me is to connect twice (or more) at the same time. For each user in separate tab. (You have to check "Session Tabs" in Options).

Then you can easy switch between users (tabs).